# Why am I getting an Segmentation fault in this implementation of binary search?

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently trying to implement binary search through recursion and created an prompt for User Input. Whenever I then input a number and searched for it I always get a segmentation fault (core dumped). I wrote this Code in the CS50 appliance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int findMidpoint(int min, int max);
int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23};
    printf("Please search for a number : ");
    int key = GetInt();
    int search = binarySearch(key, &array, array[0], array[22]);
    printf("Result: %i \n", search);
}

int findMidpoint(int min, int max)
{
    int sum = min + max;
    int mid = sum/2;

    return mid;
}

int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max)
{
    if(min > max)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int midpoint = findMidpoint(min, max);

        if(array[midpoint] < key)
        {
            binarySearch(key, array, midpoint+1, max);
        }

        else if(array[midpoint] > key)
        {
            binarySearch(key, array, midpoint-1, max);
        }
        else
        {
            return midpoint;
        }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: few things i can immediately see: (1) in `main` the arguments should be
`char** argv`and not `string argv[]` and (2) when you called `binarySearch` in your `main` you passed to it `&array` which is of type `int**`, however you should send to it `int*` which is equivalent to `array`, Why? because `int[]` is same as `int*`. (3) why you passed `binarySearch` the arguments `array[0]` and `array[22]`? you should send it the indexes, i.e `0` and `22`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application actually crashed on stack overflow, because the algorithm has not been properly implemnented.

Following the algorithm description on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Some returns added, recursive calls modified (GetInt replaced by hard coded value):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int findMidpoint(int min, int max);
int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 };
    printf("Please search for a number : ");
    int key = 10;
    int search = binarySearch(key, (int*)(&array), 0, 22);
    printf("Result: %i \n", search);
    getchar();
}

int findMidpoint(int min, int max)
{
    int sum = min + max;
    int mid = sum / 2;

    return mid;
}

int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int midpoint = findMidpoint(min, max);

        if (array[midpoint] < key)
            return binarySearch(key, array, midpoint + 1, max);
        else if (array[midpoint] > key)
            return binarySearch(key, array, min, midpoint - 1);
        else
            return midpoint;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Note the content of [Extra, Extra — Read All About It: Nearly All binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code working after a few modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int findMidpoint(int min, int max);
int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
            18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 };
    printf("Please search for a number : ");
    int key = GetInt();
    int search = binarySearch(key, array, 0, 22);
    printf("Result: %i \n", search);
}

int findMidpoint(int min, int max) {
    int sum = min + max;
    int mid = sum / 2;

    return mid;
}

int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max) {
    int midpoint = findMidpoint(min, max);
    if (array[midpoint] < key) {
        return binarySearch(key, array, midpoint + 1, max);
    } else if (array[midpoint] > key) {
        return binarySearch(key, array, min, midpoint - 1);
    } else {
        return array[midpoint];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Notice that you need to `return` the result of `binarySearch` each time you recursively call it.

Answer (score 1):

The `min` and `max` values are indices of the first and last elements, not values. You should therefore call the function with indices:

```
search = binarySearch(key, array, 0, 22);
```

Note that there is no ampersand `&` before `array`: The array will be treated as a pointer to its first element automatically. (And `&array` is not the right type here; you should have gotten a warning.)

When you recurse, you split the array in half and if the midpoint isn't your disired value, lok either at the left and right half. You got the right half part right:

```
binarySearch(key, array, midpoint+1, max);
```

but for the left part, `mitpoint - 1` is the higher bound:

```
binarySearch(key, array, min, midpoint - 1);
```

**Edit**: The other answers show it, but I missed it: You must, of course, return the results of the recursive calls to `binarySearch`.